# Flutter : How to implement a splash screen with circular wait?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I know how to show a circular wait progress indicator, but I have seen some apps showing something like a splash screen with a Circular wait in the middle. I tried to find this on Flutter documentation but couldn't able to find it.

I took a screenshot of an app that shows exactly the same circular wait which I want to learn to implement in my app :

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a splash screen or showing a full-screen loader when there's an async task going on for example an API call?

Comment: Yes something like that a full screen loader(I didn't know this term) because my app screen has a bottomNavigationBar which is immune to the normal circularProgressWait , so I want to disable that too while the app is doing some api calls for which I need a full screen loader. Thanks

Comment: You can simply use the `showGeneralDialog` from flutter and use your own widget within in your case above loader.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, If I press back button while loading, would that cancel the loading ?

Comment: you can use the willpopscope widget to avoid back press on top of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments from ibhavikmakwana, you can use showGeneralDialog(). It will displays a dialog above the current contents of the app.

This [blog post](https://codesinsider.com/flutter-full-screen-dialog-example-tutorial/) explains how to implement it.